# Magento2 - CSS merge not working at all

Tags: magento2, css, merge-css

has anyone encountered this problem?

Merge CSS is not working at all altough minifying does.

I'm still in `Developers mode`, but it's also not working in `Production mode`. I tried:

```
php bin/magento setup:upgrade
php bin/magento setup:di:compile
php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy
php bin/magento cache:flush
```

Any of these helped. I also cleared CSS/JS cache from the backend and cleared `var/view_preprocessed` manually. I also followed other threads here but no success...

Thank you for help!

Comment: What error you have ?

Comment: I actually don't get any.. Nothing happens - css is still unmerged. Only on php bin/magento setup:di:compile I get 4errors like this: errors during compilation:  Magetrend\Email\Block\Email\Block\Sales\Info Incorrect dependency in class Magetrend\Email\Block\Email\Block\Sales\Info in /home/8115764962.cloudwaysapps.com/mjkcnnfnmf/public_html/app/code/Magetrend/Email/Block/Email/Block/Sales/Info.php\Magento\Framework\View\LayoutInterface already exists in context object - But this should be related only to module, not css..

Comment: What php version you use ?

Comment: It's PHP7.0, I use Varnish and Redis cache.

Comment: I checked db -> "dev/css/merge_css_files 1" so it's active in database but no outcome

Comment: Disable that module, (I see that is not compatible with PHP 7.0 or "Dependency injection" is not worked well in this mode) and try again

Comment: Module was updated and the error is o longer there, though CSS is still unmerged. Disabeling module didn't help either.

Comment: Is there any way I could look at the  errors?

Comment: You must have enable log and it is in var/log

Answer (score 0):

Please check your pub/static folder. Maybe the www-data group doesn't have a write permision to create _cache folder. I've deleted static folder manually in command line. Therefore it can not create _cache folder.

Take a look at var/log/exceptions.log: `tail -f var/log/exception.log`
In my case:

```
[2020-09-26 12:28:24] main.CRITICAL: Le répertoire "/data/var/www/preprod/www/pub/static/_cache" ne peut être crée Warning!mkdir(): Permission denied {"exception":"[object] (Magento\\Framework\\Exception\\FileSystemException(code: 0): Le répertoire \"/data/var/www/vgc-preprod/www/pub/static/_cache\" ne peut être crée Warning!mkdir(): Permission denied at /data/var/www/preprod/www/vendor/magento/framework/Filesystem/Driver/File.php:227)"}
```

So:

`chmod 777 -r pub/static`

Hope it can help.